# How to convert a Normal Socket into a GSocket (GLib)?

Tags: sockets, system, glib

I have opened a socket say,

```
fd1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP)
```

and I have opened a GSocket say

```
GSocket socket =
            g_socket_new (AF_INET, G_SOCKET_TYPE_DATAGRAM ,
                                   G_SOCKET_PROTOCOL_UDP, &err);
```

Can someone please help me as how I can assign the fd1 into socket->fd, where fd in socket->fd is a property of GSocket.

Much Regards

Comment: Can you use `g_socket_new_from_fd` function instead?

Comment: I worked. Thank you. I was actually unaware of that function.